# vim in cmd, xterm colors completely messed up

Tags: colorscheme

I currently want to write my own vim colorscheme for the vim in cmd.

For some reason all my xterm256 colors are messed up. Every 10-15 colors the pattern of colors repeat themself... which is quite funky in an negative sense-.-

I generated all 256 colors with a little function.

```
let num = 255 
while num >= 0
exec 'hi col_'.num.' ctermbg='.num.' ctermfg=white'
exec 'syn match col_'.num.' "ctermbg='.num.':...." containedIn=ALL'
call append(0, 'ctermbg='.num.':....')
let num = num - 1
endwhile
```

And here the result:
[image]

My question is why it behaves like this and how to fix it, if possible -.-

I appreciate any help that one can provide.

Comment: What is that "cmd" thing? Does it actually support 256 colors?

Comment: What is your terminal and what is the TERM variable set to?